# Publishing Java application

Tags: java, android, publishing, google-play

After coding and testing a Java application (lets say with Eclipse, but not necessarily) what steps should be taken to publish the final version. For example, with a Android application,

you have to version your app, in an XML manifest file (mainly for the Google Play store). And then you usually sign the application using the Java keytool. Of the textbooks on Java that I have none of them mention any standard procedure for finalizing and publishing an app.

Could you explain the standard procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the first thing you'll want to do is package your app in a jar file with a main-class in the manifest.  There's a [section in the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) on that.

Then, it depends on the environments you want to support.  The easiest thing is simply to provide the user with that jar file.  In most desktop environments you can run the jar file from the file explorer by simply clicking (or double-clicking) the file.

You can make a command line version by simply wrapping the jar file with a command file.  In a UNIX/Linux environment, it's as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Beyond that, you begin needing to look into application installers, which are inherently platform-dependent.

Comment: Tried this and learned, that at least Windows and OSX do not like to execute any non-signed downloaded object. Workarounds like copying& pasting a script to a terminal is not what you want  clients of your software to force to.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is specific to publishing an Android app in the Google Play store as you have tagged your question with both ["android"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) as well as ["google-play"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play).

For creating a package for publishing an Android app to the Google Play store either using the Eclipse ADT plugin or through command line using the Ant tool, you can follow the [Preparing for Release](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) guide.

One thing which is crucial for publishing on Google Play is the requirement to have the apps signed. The steps are explained in [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).  Make sure that you store the keystore as well as the private keys for the keystore in a secure place.

Comment: Signing seems to be the essential step on all platforms, as all of them have reasonably become very restrictive in executing anything downloaded.